# how to move position of an array element only in one direction

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a 4*4 matrix  and I prompt to enter some position and that position is 4,1

(upward movement)now I want to iterate through positions (3,1) - (2,1) - (1,1)  , check those values and sometimes I must change those values  and finally print a new matrix with updates values

similarly how to iterate through (4,3) , (3,3) (2,3) , (1,3)  if some one enters the position as 4,4 (left movement)

I have tried , this so far ..

```
for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
    for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++){
        if(rowCount == specialRow && columnCount == specialColumn)

        {
            if(board[rowCount][columnCount] = 1 )
            {
                printf("%d \t",board[rowCount][columnCount]);
                board[rowCount][columnCount] = 0 ;

            }
        }

        for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
            for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++)
                printf("%d \t",board[rowCount][columnCount]);

            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

- rows  means maximum rows
- columns means maximum columns
- rowCount for row iteration
- columnCount for colum iteration
- specialRow and sepcialColumn for the new position entered (from this position we have scan values in upward/left/backward directions) .

Comment: `if(board[rowCount][columnCount] = 1 )` : `=` --> `==` ?

Comment: i did'nt get it.  are you saying to change my statement in if condition as board[rowCount][columnCount] = 1  to  board[rowCount][columnCount] =  --> == 0

Comment: lol, No he is not suggesting that.  Quite rightly - he is suggesting you examine your use of = and perhaps consider ==

Comment: To trick yourself out of doing such mistakes again you might like to start using Yoda Conditions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your array first based on some condition let's say the input is 4 4 so you should be doing

```
for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {

    for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++){
        if(columnCount == (specialColumn-1))

        {
            if(board[rowCount][columnCount] == 1 )
            {
                printf("%d \t",board[rowCount][columnCount]);
                board[rowCount][columnCount] = 0 ;

            }
        }
}
}
```

Now assuming the required modifications are made to your matrix print them out seperately

```
   for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
   for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++)
     printf("%d \t",board[rowCount][columnCount]);

     printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: No problem :)  Easily overlooked. Merry Xmas

Comment: ya so far , its working but i need  the  values in the position specialRow , specialColumn to be unchanged.  Even those  values are modified

Comment: @Avinash You sound contradictory now. If you don't want to touch `1*3` `2*3` `3*3` and `4*4` then when you are that position just don't muck with those values

Comment: see my first line its  4*4 matrix  and special position is (4,1)  , i want to  change values (3,1) (2,1) and (1,1) and here even the value of 4,1 is changing

Comment: @Avinash Check the edits. If I understand correctly if the input is 4 4 then the value 4 3 should not be touched and rest of the values `1 3` `2 3` and `3 3` will be modified and my code does this

Comment: if the input is 4 4 then 4 4 should remain unchanged and all the elements above it 4 3 , 3 3 , 2 3 should be changed  (only upper elements not all elemnents in the column) suppose if input is 4 3 then only 4 2 , 4 1 changes .

Comment: @Avinash If you input 4 3 then isn't it that all `3 3` `2 3` and `1 3` should change? I am not getting your pattern. If you have 4*4 matrix then 0-3 should be your array index it can't be 4

Comment: only 3 3 , 2  3 , 1 3 should change. remaining all should be unchanged ( pattern is upward movement from that position)